# Cannot access urlbar in firefox addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I cannot access urlbar in firefox addon

I can't access the urlbar object as a firefox add-on in any way, if I add it to permissions in the manifest.json firefox tells me "Invalid extension permission: urlbar", but if I request "tab" as permission, it shows me as property:

```
Reading manifest: Warning processing permissions: Error processing permissions.1: Value "tab" must either: must either [must either [be one of [
      "clipboardRead",
      "clipboardWrite",
      "geolocation",
      "idle",
      "notifications"
    ], 
  /********* A LOTS OF PERMISSIONS ************/
  be one of [
    "urlbar" // <<< RIGHT HERE!!!
  ], be one of [
    "contextualIdentities"
  ], be one of [
    "dns"
  ],
  /********* A LOTS OF PERMISSIONS ************/
  be one of [
    "theme"
  ], or match the pattern /^experiments(\.\w+)+$/
], or must either [be one of [
    "<all_urls>"
  ], must either [match the pattern /^(https?|wss?|file|ftp|\*):\/\/(\*|\*\.[^*/
    ]+|[^*/
    ]+)\/.*$/, or match the pattern /^file:\/\/\/.*$/
  ], or match the pattern /^resource:\/\/(\*|\*\.[^*/
  ]+|[^*/
  ]+)\/.*$|^about:/
]
```

How do I access the urlbar? My intention is that after making a redirection of a fantasy url (like http://something.server.internal) redirect to another page (which I already do) but not change the url in the address bar. As an alternative I have thought of loading an iframe with the content of the page to be redirected but I cannot control the content of the page that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The URL bar is not accessible WebExtensions addons. Instead there is the `omnibox` API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/omnibox

But you don't need to use `omnibox` for redirections. Instead listeners for `webRequest.onBeforeRequest` can do that. See also:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest#Examples

Comment: i already do this omnibox via, but doesnt work, you known how use the omnibox to change (at least) the url without change the entire page?, thanks for the answer and the time

Comment: Ah, sorry I totally misunderstood your intention.You try to show an content with a URL different from its original one, in other words, you try to fake the URL visible at the urlbar? Then an addon [DITM (Developer In The Middle)](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/ditm/) does that, with `browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`. [Its background.js](https://github.com/arai-a/ditm/blob/master/background.js) may give a hint to do. It blocks a native request and returns completely replaced contents to Firefox.